# Adhoc distribution: App Install progress doesn't show and installs in background

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I have setup AdHoc Distribution for an iOS App and while it works fine, for some reason when I download the App, it never shows downloading progress.

It does install in the background as App icon appears when it downloads quickly.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If the app works you are doing everything fine. Maybe your app is very tiny and iOS completes the installation before being able to show a progress bar.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it actually takes some time (up to 2 minutes) to install.

Comment: This has been common now a days